Searching a regex wherein the key is enclosed between two double quotes in Splunk
Trying to search something like this :
"requestUrlLength": 10112, "requestBodyLength": 8626

Tried using the following Splunk queries but no success:
| rex field=_raw "\"requestUrlLength\":\s(?<requestUrlLength>\d+),"
| table requestUrlLength
| stats count by requestUrlLength
| sort -count

| rex field=_raw (?<requestUrlLength>"\"requestUrlLength\":\s\d+,")
| table requestUrlLength
| stats count by requestUrlLength
| sort -count

Any help appreciated.

The regex must be "requestUrlLength":\s*(?<requestUrlLength>\d+). What does not work? What do you get and what do you expect?

Tried the above regex but again it doesn't work.
I expect events such that say there are 10 requestUrlLength with say value 100, then one column of the table should have "requestUrlLength": 100 and another column should have value 10. Likewise all the other requestUrlLength with different values and their total count should get displayed.
Hope this helps understand the expected results.

This looks like part of JSON. Can you parse the JSON and match the object properties?

The issue is, that you  escaped < for the named capture group. Quotation marks only require single escape. Try this minimal-run-anywhere expample:
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="\"requestUrlLength\": 10112, \"requestBodyLength\": 8626"
| rex "\"requestUrlLength\":\s*(?<requestUrlLength>\d+),"


Thanks @DuesserBaest for pointing that out. It was a mistake from my end. But again the above query doesn't work. I've edited my answer to include a link from Splunk community which confirms of a bug from Splunk w.r.t. double quotes in a raw string.

@mandar then you misformulated your question and you want to search in the string: "requestUrlLength": 10112, "requestBodyLength": 8626? Because the sting you proposed can be parsed with the suggested regex - the SPL in my answer does run and extract the desired result

yes the string in eval can be searched which even I tried initially but the string in question cannot be (that's why I posted it here). You can have a look at the link that I have provided from Splunk community for further details.

| rex field=_raw (?<RequestUrlLength>"\\\"requestUrlLength\\\\\":\s+\d+,")

There is a bug in Splunk I suppose. If there are more double quotes in your text, you shall need to add seven back-slashes and so on.
Hope this helps someone..
Edit - Link from Splunk Community which confirms of bug in Splunk.
